# Is this a violation of the single responsibility principle (SRP)

Tags: android, kotlin, single-responsibility-principle

Do the methods `getSummary` and `getMovementType` violate the SRP since they know too much (`Context`)? These methods are used in a `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

```
abstract class Movement(
    val movementId: Int = 0,
    val created: Date = Date(),
    val createdBy: String = "",
    val movementActive: String = Constants.ACTIVE,
    var quantity: Double = 0.0,
    var material: Material = Material()
) {
    abstract fun getSummary(context: Context): String
    abstract fun getMovementType(context: Context): String
}


data class Entry(
    val id: Int = 0,
    var observation: String = "",
    var warehouse: Warehouse = Warehouse()
) : Movement() {

    override fun getSummary(context: Context) =
        context.getString(R.string.title_warehouse) + ": ${warehouse.name}. " +
        context.getString(R.string.title_material) + ": ${material.name}. " +
        context.getString(R.string.quantity) + ": $quantity. " +
        context.getString(R.string.observation) + ": $observation. " +
        context.getString(R.string.user) + ": $createdBy"

    override fun getMovementType(context: Context) = context.getString(R.string.title_entry)
}
```

Comment: this question is going to receive answers based on opinions and that's off-topic for stack overflow, you might be better off asking this question on another community

Answer (score 2):

**No, it doesn't.**

Whatever method knows (context in your case), SRP is about to "do single responsibility".

I see your methods only return some values from context. Don't let them do anything else (for example, set something to somewhere or send something to somewhere) and you follow SRP

Comment: disagree, this method could easily sit in the adapter instead of the model, considering the fact that the adapter is the component responsible for the showing of this data. this class is now responsible for the transportation of data AS WELL AS knowing how to display it

Comment: By the way the adapter list is of type `Movement` and of course there are many child classes, each one showing different information.

Comment: @a_local_nobody the question was "Do methods violate the SRP ?". Well, methods don't. There were no questions about the class responsibility

Comment: i guess that's fair :) the methods themselves don't, but i don't agree with having them inside the model

Comment: @a_local_nobody agree with you, but this is not an answer for the question